# How to apply effect inside WPF UIElement OnRender method?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I want to apply a blurr effect to a specific geometry, inside WPF UIElement OnRender method.

I have code like below.

```
        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

            using (var dc = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
            {
                dc.DrawGeometry(null, _borderColorPen, _textGeometry);
            }

            drawingVisual.Effect = new BlurEffect { Radius = 5 };

            //  drawing geometry with blurr
            drawingContext.DrawDrawing(drawingVisual.Drawing);

            //  drawing geometry without blurr
            drawingContext.DrawGeometry(_foreColorBrush, null, _textGeometry);
        }
```

But blurr effect does'nt work.

Why is it?
And what is the best way to do something like this?

Comment: you did not apply any Brush to the dc.DrawGeometry, you should at least set Brushes.Transparent

Comment: I'm only drawing a border for it. I set Brushes.Trasparent, but it does not work.

Comment: OnRender is the wrong place. Try to add the effect from an Loaded event handler or from the constructor or set it using XAML (e.g. locally or via Style).